# ALTITUDE_CLAMP_TO_GROUND error in GE 7.0.1.8244

Tags: kml, google-earth

I think I have found an error in GE V7.0.1.8244. I create a KML route file and display it with `setAltitudeMode` set to `ALTITUDE_CLAMP_TO_GROUND`. In GE V6.2.2.6613 it displays correctly but in V7.0.1.8244 (currently beta) it does not. Same program source, same data. See attached image here:

[image: http://www.gtrek.co.uk/ge.jpg].

Any ideas anybody other than installing an other version of GE?

Comment: When you say setAltitudeMode() and ALTITUDE_CLAMP_TO_GROUND this implies GE API/plugin in web browser but screenshot looks like the GE Desktop client. Can you share a snippet of KML to show this issue?

Comment: Hi Jason, snipped here www.gtrek.co.uk/test2.kml. zoom right in close to see the effect. Why two negative clicks, I'm only asking a question ?

Comment: +1 to redress the unfounded negative marks, seems like a well researched, clear question to me.

Answer (score 2):

This is clearly a bug in GE 7.0. A few of the elements in the KML test file are out of order but nothing to cause this problem. Even if you drop the altitude values and change altitudeMode to *relativeToGround* it gets worse not better. Neither DirectX or OpenGL mode makes a difference.

You can report the issue here to get any updates on the problem:
http://code.google.com/p/earth-issues/issues/list

Might be an error in elevation data. You can also see this error in the [sample line example](http://kml-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/kml/Placemark/LineString/tessellate.kml) if you zoom close to the path.

Only short-term fix is reverting back to GE 6.2.2 if want to view this KML correctly, otherwise, wait for a fix.

UPDATE: Issue in Google Earth issue tracker can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/earth-issues/issues/detail?id=1503).

Comment: Issue 1503 already logged, somebody got there before me 4 days ago. Thanks for checking it out for me.

Answer (score 1):

It does look like a bug, rather than down grading though you could look to use one of the [Google Earth extensions](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#kmlextensions) - specifically the `gx:altitudeOffset` element. From the docs...

> A KML extension, in the Google extension namespace, that modifies how
>   the altitude values are rendered. This offset allows you to move an
>   entire LinearRing up or down as a unit without modifying all the
>   individual coordinate values that make up the LinearRing. (Although
>   the LinearRing is displayed using the altitude offset value, the
>   original altitude values are preserved in the KML file.) Units are in
>   meters.

This should allow you to raise the path by a meter so that the clipping doesn't occur.
It is also worth noting that...

> In Google Earth, a Polygon with an  of clampToGround
>   follows lines of constant bearing; however, a LinearRing (by itself)
>   with an  of clampToGround follows great circle lines.

So perhaps you need to adjust your path to account for this discrepancy?